# match substring against text values arranged in a excel table

Tags: excel, substring, match

I am trying to achieve this result: assign a category to a document based on its title, or part of its title.

| Title | Category |
| --- | --- |
| correspondence | Correspondence |
| Note Transmission Correspondence | Correspondence |
| Advisors Evaluation Report | Report |
| Country Notes | Correspondence |
| Annual Portfolio Report | Report |
| Appointment Letter | Correspondence |

The categories are arranged into a table (docCategories) where each row starts with a unique category name, and is followed by a set of labels that match entirely or partially with the document title.

| Category | Label | Label2 | Label3 | Label4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Correspondence** | *Letter* | *Memo* | *Note* | *Correspondence* |
| **Report** | *Dashboard* | *Report* |  |  |

The formula will take the document title and check if it matches any of the labels (with wild cards), so to return the unique category in the first position in the same row of the matched label.

*Appointment Letter* -> matches label:letter -> **cat:Correspondence**

I have made it working with this formula to be copied in the Category column:

```
=INDEX(docCategories;MIN(IF(docCategories=A2;ROW(docCategories)))-1;MIN(IF(docCategories=A2;1)))
```

And only if the title is exact matching of the entire label (e.g. *Correspondence* -> matches label:correspondence -> **cat:Correspondence**).

I am looking to have it working for matching on part of the title (e.g. *Appointment Letter* -> matches label:letter -> **cat:Correspondence**).

I have tried and failed to change the `docCategories=<title>` into something that can match the substring of the title, even applying the `SPLITEXT(<title>)` it still fails to give me the expected result.

Who can think of a creative solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works for any number of categories and for any number of labels on any category. It also identifies if no labels were found and also if more than one label was found from a different category. Since the question doesn't specify any specific excel version tag I assume Microsoft Office 365 function can be used.

On cell `I2` put the following formula:

```
=LET(rng, A2:E3, texts, G2:G9, lkupValues, B2:E3, categories, INDEX(rng,,1),
  BYROW(texts, LAMBDA(text,LET(
    reduceResult, REDUCE("",categories, LAMBDA(acc,c, LET(
      lkup, XLOOKUP(c,categories, lkupValues), searchLabels, FILTER(lkup, lkup<>0),
      IF(SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(searchLabels,text))))=0, acc,
        IF(acc="", c, "MORE THAN ONE CATEGORY FOUND"))
    ))), IF(reduceResult<>"", reduceResult, "CATEGORY NOT FOUND")
  )))
)
```

and here is the corresponding output:

[image: sample excel file]

The last two rows **Title** column were added to test the Non-Happy paths.

### Explanation

We use `LET` function to define the names to be used and to avoid repeating the same calculation. If in your excel version you have `DROP` function available, then the name: `lkupValues` can be defined as follow: `DROP(rng,,1)`.

The main idea is to iterate over `texts` values via `BYROW` and for each `text` we invoke `SEARCH` function for all categories. When the first input argument of `SEARCH` is an array, it returns an array of the same shape indicating the start of the index position of the labels found in `text` or `#VALUE!` if no labels were found.

**Note**: `SEARCH` is not case sensitive, if that is not the case, then replace it with `FIND`.

We use `REDUCE` function to iterate over all `categories` to find a match. For each category (`c`) we find the corresponding labels via `XLOOKUP`. Since not all categories have the same number of labels, for example `Report` has fewer labels than the `Correspondence` category. We need to adjust it to remove empty labels. The name `searchLabels` filters the result to only non-empty labels.

For checking if labels were not found we use the following condition:

```
SUM(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(searchLabels,text))))=0
```

`ISNUMBER` converts the `SEARCH` result to `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. `N` function converts the result to equivalent `0`,`1` values.

If the condition is `TRUE`, it returns the accumulator (`acc` initialized to an empty string). If the condition is `FALSE`, some labels were found, then it returns the category (`c`) if `acc` is empty, i.e. no previous categories were found. If `acc` is not empty any previous category was found, so it returns `MORE THAN ONE CATEGORY FOUND`.

Finally, if the result of `REDUCE` (`reduceResult`) is an empty string, it means the accumulator was not updated after initialization, so no labels were found for any category and it is indicated with the output: `CATEGORY NOT FOUND`.

Comment: Dear David, this obviously work like expected! and yes, I am working with Office365. I did ask for a creative solution, and yours goes beyond that. I have carefully read your explanation, and since you have captured the case of "more than one category found", I have been now thinking that having more than one category separated with a ";" can turn to be useful. The solution only flags for more than one (based on `acc`), so how can instead accumulate multiple positive search result and "print" them out in the cell?.  Thanks a million!

Comment: @Menelao just replace `MORE THAN ONE CATEGORY FOUND` with: `acc &”;”& c`. From the top of my head. I haven’t tested it. By the way you can upvote the answer too if you consider it.

Comment: Daer @David, I didn't know I had the ability to upvote, I tried in the past, and now I know I have enough reputation to do it!!! I have followed your intuition and did that replacement is doing the job greatly. I have a collection of 900 titles, and I have been checking how they classify yesterday. I noticed that `Tranformation` gets classified as `Form`, since the label `form` is matched against trans`form`ation. Something that can be fixed by settings in SEARCH?

Comment: This is how it is supposed to work. It finds a substring writhing a string. If you want to search for words (delimited by space). Then you can define the label `Form`  adding space in both sides or just at the end to include the case it is the first word of the title.